# How to color convert a texture before it's time to display with openGL ES

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm working on a video player (based on openGL ES) for iPhone where the frames arrive at the renderer at a rate faster than the display rate (33ms). As the frame arrive I store them and then when it's time to display a frame, I use an openGL shader to make a color conversion and the RGB converted image is displayed on the screen. What I would like to do is to be able to convert the frames as they arrive but I'm not sure how to proceed. Can some one describe the steps needed to accomplish this? Also is this necessary, what I mean is it a good practice to do the color conversion right when the frame is received and only swap the buffers when the display callback is fired?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to avoid the Shader part? Actually Shaders are much faster for this purpose.

Comment: No, I do want to use the shaders. Maybe the answer is to use the frame buffer objects?